# Java → Convert date string to a relative time stamp

Tags: java, android, date, time, timestamp

I'm looking for a rational way of **converting** something like the following:

> 2015-07-15 | 04:31 | 2015-07-29

to a relative time-stamp like

> 'About two weeks ago' | '20 minutes ago' | '3 days ago'.

What is the best approach to this in **Java** (*Android SDK*)?

Comment: Start from the top and check year->month->week->etc.

Answer (score 1):

There Is a utility for this, pretty time: :http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/